# Framework to use for multiple webparts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

We are currently using Angular 1.5 for some SharePoint customization. We are still on 2013 on-prem and we usually have multiple webparts on one page, each featuring a single AngularJS app. This is not how AngularJS works, I know, but this was the best way to achieve the modularity for us. However, we get some errors in the console saying, that AngularJS was already loaded (ofcourse) and some directives aren't working properly.

We started to investigate Angular2 just to come up with the conslusion that there is no OOTB way to implement multiple Angular2 apps on one page.

I.e. we have an aspx Site which features 5 Webparts: 1 Navigation (Custom AngularJS), one document library, one content editor webpart (Custom AngularJS), one news webpart (Custom AngularJS) and a webpart showing some persons (Custom AngularJS). We have found no way to implement this with Angular2 without doing it as a Single Page Application.

Would such an approach possible with React?

Comment: ng2 is all or nothing.. ng1 should work.  React is a totally different beast you have to learn and master. Instead of solely looking at Frameworks, also investigate how much time is involved doing it with vanilla JavaScript. (but I am biased here, the projects I actually use ng or React in production, I can count on one hand) Note: If you are looking at Frameworks also learn what Polymer is.. that's a Framework that shrinks the more browsers (IE & Edge are always the last ones) support modern W3C WebComponents